# Why am I unable to create this file?

Tags: c, windows, file-io

Here is my code example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* fileName = "%appdata%\\log.log";
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(fileName, "a+");
    time_t startTime = time(0);
    fputs("Started logging at: ", file);
    fputs(ctime(&startTime), file);
    fclose(file);
    printf("%s", fileName);
    return 0;
}
```

My program gets down to the `printf()` statement, and prints:

> %appdata%\log.log

I know that is a viable location for a Windows computer, so why is the program unable to make the `.log` file? What is a workaround that I should use to make it work?

Comment: You should call one of the CSIDL or known folder API functions. Don't rely on the environment variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `fopen` call has no idea what `%appdata%` is, as it can't magically convert that into a path. You have to expand the path yourself using the [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. e.g. (untested):

```
char dest[MAX_PATH];
ExpandEnvironmentStrings(fileName, dest, MAX_PATH);
file = fopen(dest, "a+");
```

Comment: Brilliant! After a little fooling around, I got it to work. This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
%appdata%
```

is an environment variable, they are not automatically resolved and need their values to explicitly be retrieved using [getenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) function call.